# How to check earphone port is working or not

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I am doing one application. In that i need to connect headphones to device and check is it connected or not. But i have another device, that device earphone port is not working. If connect headphones to that device, it's return as not connected. So decided to check earphone port is working or not, searched many places, but i didn't get any information about how to check earphone port is working or not. So if anybody know about this please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure though but you might try this.

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession 
sharedInstance] currentRoute];
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) {
    if ([[desc portType] 
isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
        return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

If it returns false then you might check whether port is working or not.

Comment: That's what i need,How to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect the earphone port hardware issues programmatically.

Instead,you can check either the headphones are plugged-in or not using the below method and provide a generic message to the user.

```
if (![self isHeadsetPluggedIn]) {
    //please plugin your headset/ ur earphone port is not working
}

- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
        AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
        for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) {
            if ([[desc portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
                return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
```